# Debugging with Nsight makes .exe stop working

Tags: cuda, nsight

I have a solution in VS2010 which contains multiple projects. The project I want to debug via Nsight is marked as a StartUp Project. Following in VS the root `Nsight->Start Cuda Debugging` makes the `.exe` to crash.

[image]

I have tried to debug with Nsight a cuda SDK sample, vector addition, and everything is fine. So I started suspecting project configurations. Nonetheless, the configurations of the sdk sample and the project I am trying to debug is almost the same except from the command line. Bellow, there is the command line of the project that do not debug.

## Driver API (NVCC Compilation Type is .cubin, .gpu, or .ptx)

set CUDAFE_FLAGS=--sdk_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\"
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\bin\nvcc.exe" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"     -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -o MP7.dir\Debug\%(Filename)%(Extension).obj "%(FullPath)"

## Runtime API (NVCC Compilation Type is hybrid object or .c file)

set CUDAFE_FLAGS=--sdk_dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\"
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\bin\nvcc.exe" --use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"     -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g    -Xcompiler "/EHsc  /nologo  /Zi    " -o MP7.dir\Debug\%(Filename)%(Extension).obj "%(FullPath)"

Could you please anyone make a clarification?

Thank you!

PS: VS2010, 64x solution, Win7 64x, CUDA SDK 64x, Nsight 3.2 64x

Comment: I am suspecting that because in the cpu debugging I am passing some command arguments to debug the .exe, maybe gpu debugging do not pass the arguments and the .exe crashes. The question here is, does the Nsight debugger read the same arguments that are set in project debugging properties?

Comment: Problem solved: `right click on project properties-> Nsight User Properties->Command line arguments` and pass your arguments. __PS:__ Maybe I will delete the post because it was not a big problem at all.

Comment: Please either delete the post, or provide an answer to your own question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the project properties, in the Debugging tag I was passing some command arguments that the Nsight debugger could not access maybe. The problem solved by passing the same command arguments into the Nsight debugger. Look, figure bellow.

[image]